# Change Shiny GUI with user input, accordingly

Tags: r, shiny

In the following code, there are editable table and check boxes.

If the one of the component of the column vector named `q` in the table are changed by user, then the number of check boxes also change.

For example, if maximum integer in `q` is changed to  7, then GUI is also changed automatically such that there are 7 check boxes.

[image]

[image]

**The following code is the answer of @Ben. Thank you Ben.**

```
  library(rhandsontable)
    library(shiny)

    foo <- function(M = 2,
                    Q = 3,
                    C = 4) {
      DF <- data.frame(
        m = 1,
        q = 2,
        c = 3,

        # To make empty cells, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA.

        h= rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C),  # Here, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA
        f = rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C) # Here, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA
      )

      ui <- shiny::fluidPage(

        shiny::sidebarLayout(
          shiny::sidebarPanel(


            rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
            shiny::em( "Modality ID"),
            shiny::h6(shiny::helpText("Specify the modality ID to be drawn")),



            uiOutput("checkbox")



          ),
          shiny::mainPanel()
        )
      )

      server <-  function(input, output) {
        values <- shiny::reactiveValues()

        ## Handsontable
        shiny::observe({
          if

          (!is.null(input$hot)) {
            DF = rhandsontable::hot_to_r(input$hot)
          } else {
            if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
              DF <- DF
            else
              DF <- values[["DF"]]
          }
          values[["DF"]] <- DF
          values[["dataList"]] <- list(
            NL = input$Number_of_lesions,
            NI = input$Number_of_images,
            h = DF$h,
            f = DF$f,
            m = DF$m,
            q = DF$q,
            c = DF$c,
            C = input$C,
            M = input$M,
            Q = input$Q
          )
        })




        output$checkbox <- renderUI({
          checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "q", choices = seq(1:max(values$DF$q)))
        }) 







        output$hot <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({
          DF <- values[["DF"]]
          if (!is.null(DF))
            rhandsontable::rhandsontable(DF,
                                         stretchH = "all")
        })
      }
      shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
      return(invisible())

    } # function

    foo()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of individual `checkboxInput` in your ui, you could use a `checkboxGroupInput` instead:

```
uiOutput("checkbox")
```

Then, you can include the number of checkboxes dynamically based on the maximum value in your `q` column:

```
output$checkbox <- renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "q", choices = seq(1:max(values$DF$q)))
})
```

This is quite simplified, but it could be expanded upon depending on needs, including checkbox labels, validation of maximum number of choices, and others.